# Makefile: check if multiple variables are set

Tags: makefile, sh

In my **Makefile** I want to check if multiple environments variables are set.
But I don't want to write multiple `ifndef` for each one. I just want an array of variables to make it reusable.

```
check-variables:
  for var in var1 var2 var3 ; do \
    if [ -z "$$var" ] ; then \
      echo "$$var is not set"; exit 1; \
    fi \
  done
```

But it's not working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a make issue, it's a shell issue.  If you ran that script at your shell prompt (changing `$$` back to `$` as make will do, of course) it wouldn't work either.  Until you can get the command to work at your shell prompt, you can't get it to work in a makefile.

The shell command would be:

```
for var in var1 var2 var3 ; do \
  if [ -z "$var" ] ; then \
    echo "$var is not set"; exit 1; \
  fi \
done
```

You can see why this doesn't do what you want: you're checking the shell variable `var` every time.  What you're trying to do is check the value of the variable which is named by the value of `$var`.  To do this you need eval (the shell's eval, not make's `eval` function):

```
for var in var1 var2 var3 ; do \
  eval test -n \"\$$var\" \
      || { echo "$var is not set"; exit 1; }; \
done
```

You should discover that the above will work in the shell, then you need to put it back into the makefile (and double all the `$`).

Comment: Thank for the correction, you're right, but anyway I can't make it work inside Makefile. I tried lot of combinations using eval and \$$$var, $"$$var", "\$$$var", etc...

Comment: Then that must mean the variables are not set.  If you add `echo 'var1=$$var1 var2=$$var2 var3=$$var3'` in your makefile rule, what do you see?  Where are these variables supposed to come from?

Comment: It should be **EXACTLY** the same as the example above, except **EVERY** `$` must be doubled.  Do not add/remove backslashes, quotes, etc.: make doesn't care about backslashes or quotes.  So it should be `test -z \"\$$$$var\"` and `$$var` in the echo.

Comment: Basically, when make prints the shell script it will run, it should look identical to the one in my answer.

Comment: Also, "I can't make it work" is not something we can help with.  Please show (in your question, not in comments where it can't be formatted) what make command you run, what output you get, and why that is wrong/what you expected.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, it have tried a lot of combinations except with 4 $. Now it understand how it works. Great answer!

Comment: It's strange... Your code works now, but AFTER the for loop, it always trows an Error 1 and make doesn't continue its execution. But if I add a simple line like `echo -n;` INSIDE   `for` just before ending the loop (before `done`) it works. No clue.

Comment: Hm, yes, you should invert the test.  I will edit my answer.  The reason is that the exit code of the script is the exit code of the last command executed in the script.  If the last command executed (the test) fails then the script exits with a failure then make thinks the entire thing failed.

Comment: Fixed, sorry about that!